# Advantages/Disadvantages to using Cut/Paste instead of Copy/Paste

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

This could apply to any operating system that supports clipboards stably.

Out of habit, I use `(Command)Ctrl+C` / `Ctrl+V`, and quickly delete with one more keystroke.

But it came to me, is there an actual advantage (other than saving a delete keystroke) to `Ctrl+X` / `Ctrl+V`?

Is it a less taxing move to the computer to cut instead of copy/delete?  Should I be as trusting in the OS to never forget what I've cut before I paste it?

Answer (score 2):

If terms of file management, yes Cut and Paste can save time if you're doing an operation on the same disk.  Reason being the file system will simply update the pointer to the file rather than duplicate the data.  If you are going to be copying between disks, it makes more sense to use the Copy instead of Cut function, in the instance where you accidentally choose the wrong file.  (This is why it's the default option for drag-drop)

As for applications/text, it's an UI functionality decision, in my opinion. It saves time and gives an additional helpful option for the user. Thus you can see why it has been the convention for many years across many OSes.